How to derive this conditional distribution $P(X<x|X<Y)$?
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables. $X>0$ and $Y>0$. I tried to derive the conditional probability $P(X<x|X<Y)$, which is a truncated distribution of $X$ observed only if $X<Y$, as follows:
\begin{align*}
 P(X<x|X<Y)&=\frac{P(X<x, X<Y)}{P(X<Y)}\\
 &=\frac{P(X<x) \cdot I(x<Y)}{P(X<Y)} \\
 &=\frac{F_x(x)}{F_x(Y)} ,\,\,\, 0 < x < Y \\
\end{align*}
$I(\cdot)$ is an indicator function.
Any issues with the derivation?

Why $P(X < x, X < Y) = P(X < x) \cdot I(X < Y)$ ?

I think I should write "$P(X<x, X<Y)=P(X<x) \cdot I(x<Y)$". The values of $x$ needs to be less than $Y$

The second equality is not only wrong, it is meaningless.

@Vincent  The values for $x$ do not need to be less than $Y$.  The event is that both $x$ and $Y$ are greater than $X$; with no restriction on the ordering of $x$ and $Y$.  $$\mathsf P(X<x, X<Y) = \mathsf P(X<x<Y)+\mathsf P(X<Y\leqslant x)$$

@Vincent  The values for $x$ do not need to be less than $Y$.  The event is that both $x$ and $Y$ are greater than $X$; with no restriction on the ordering of $x$ and $Y$. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X<x, X<Y) &= \mathsf P(X<x<Y)+\mathsf P(X<Y\leqslant x)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(X<Y)-\mathsf P(x\leqslant X<Y)\end{align}$$

thanks, Graham. here
\begin{align}
P(X<x<Y)=\int^{\infty}_x \int^y_0 f_x(x) dx f_y(y) dy
\end{align}
\begin{align} P(X<Y<x)=\int^x_0 \int^y_0 f_x(x) dx f_y(y) dy
\end{align}  I wonder what is the expression of $P(X<x|X<Y)$

Well, that indicates that:$$\mathsf P(X<Y)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^y f_X(x);f_Y(y),\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy$$

PS: check your first equation.  The bounds are wrong.  Also do not use $x$ for both a free and bound variable.
